# Why is viewWillDisapper not called?

Tags: iphone

Why is viewWillDisapper not called when I push back button in navigation bar of myViewController?

```
TheController *theController = [[TheController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];             
UINavigationController *aNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:theController];
self.naviController = aNavigationController;
[aNavigationController release];
[theController release];
[self.view addSubview:naviController.view];
```

// This is TheController.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];           
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
    [myViewController release];
}
```

// This is MyViewController.m.
   MyViewConroller is subclass of UIViewController.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    // I want to override back button behavior. But, this is not called.
}
```

viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, viewDidDisappear, viewDidUnLoad are not called either.

Comment: Are you adding the UINavigationController's view as a subview of some other view?

Comment: Does MyViewController actually have a view?

Comment: I did addSubView for parent of MyViewController. I edited that part.

Comment: Because MyViewController is subclass of UIViewController, it has view. It works fine except this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to override the left navigation bar button behavior, you can simply replace the leftBarButtonItem with a button with a custom action:

```
// Place this in you viewDidLoad method
UIBarButtonItem *customBack = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(customAction)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBack;
[customBack release];
```

You can also provide a custom view for the UIBarButtonItem if you prefer.

Comment: Isn't it difficult to make cancel button look like back button?

Comment: If you just want the button to say "Back", the easiest thing to do is just use [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView, and provide a UIImageView of the backButton. If you want some more control, there's a very nice explanation + code here: http://idevrecipes.com/2011/01/12/how-do-iphone-apps-instagramreederdailybooth-implement-custom-navigationbar-with-variable-width-back-buttons/  that lets you customize the navBar easily.

Answer (score -1):

You should call viewWillAppear in your parent view controller.

http://bit.ly/q9vQiu

Comment: viewWillAppear in parent view is not called either.