# How to clear previous text in UITextView before writing text?

Tags: iphone

I want to clear previous text written on UITextView before new text is written on it.
I did like this.

```
textView.text = @"";
textView.text = @"something";
```

But, previous text is not cleared. It overlaps with current text.
Textview is non-editable.

Comment: Add NSLog(@"Text Field Content : %@",textField.text); after first line, what is the output ? Did you create textField programmatically or using Interface builder ?

Comment: I am sorry. It is textView, not textField. I edited. I created textview programmatically.

Answer (score 9):

You need to implement the UITextViewDelegate and the method, `textViewDidBeginEditing`. The following code sets the textView's text to `@""` (nothing) when it starts editing.

```
- (void) textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *) textView {
  [textView setText:@""];
}
```

Comment: textViewDidBeginEditing is not called. TextView is inside ViewController. I put textView in root viewController, it is called.  But, my viewController is pushed viewController, it is not called.

Comment: Set `textView.delegate` to `self`.

Answer (score 3):

**Here is a code for swift**

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
        txtView.text = ""
        txtView.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }

func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
     if txtView.text.isEmpty {
         txtView.text = "Write your comment."
         txtView.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
     }
}

func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if text == "\n"  // Recognizes enter key in keyboard
        {
            textView.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
```

**Note : give delegate to your textview**

Answer (score 2):

Set the selected range to the entire text of the textView first:

```
    [textView setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(0, textView.text.length)];
    [textView setText:@""];
```

As in:

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    //  Make the textView visible in-case the keyboard has covered it
    [table scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1] 
                 atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop 
                         animated:YES];

    // Keyboard toolbar prev/next buttons
    [nextPreviousControl setEnabled:YES forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [nextPreviousControl setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:1];

    //
    // Erase all text in the textView before editing starts:
    // 
    [textView setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(0, textView.text.length)];
    [textView setText:@""];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: textViewShoulBeginEditing is not called. TextView is inside ViewController. I put textView in root viewController, it is called.  But, my viewController is pushed viewController, it is not called.

Comment: put this in your `ViewController` that has the `UITextView` in the `viewDidLoad` method:  `[textView setDelegate:self];`.

Comment: And in the header file for your `ViewController` add this `<UITextViewDelegate>` like this -> `@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate> {`

Comment: I know how to add delegate. But, for some unknown reason, that method is never called. It works fine for root ViewController.

Comment: Can you post more of the code that is behaving this way?  It's tough to debug accurately without the source.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336144/why-is-viewwilldisapper-not-called is the link I posted. TextView is inside MyViewController.h. I think, I have to look more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Set the [**clearsOnBeginEditing**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006888-CH3-SW20) for your text field.